# The oslo config get error: raise NoSuchOptError(name) oslo_config.cfg.NoSuchOptError: no such option iteritems in group [DEFAULT]

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I follow this [oslo config tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMJTFl00OGk):

in the `2:00`, there:

```
from oslo_config import cfg

from pprint import pprint

res = [{k:v} for k, v in cfg.CONF.iteritems()]

pprint(res)
```

In the tutorial there print `[]`,

but in my PyCharm, there is a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2193, in __getattr__
    return self._get(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2627, in _get
    value, loc = self._do_get(name, group, namespace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2645, in _do_get
    info = self._get_opt_info(name, group)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2845, in _get_opt_info
    raise NoSuchOptError(opt_name, group)
oslo_config.cfg.NoSuchOptError: no such option iteritems in group [DEFAULT]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bush/Desktop/TestIOS/TestPython/testDemo01/testDemo01/test16.py", line 15, in <module>
    res = [{k:v} for k, v in cfg.CONF.iteritems()]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oslo_config/cfg.py", line 2197, in __getattr__
    raise NoSuchOptError(name)
oslo_config.cfg.NoSuchOptError: no such option iteritems in group [DEFAULT]
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer version of `oslo_config.cfg`, you can use `items()` for your purpose:

```
es = [{k:v} for k, v in cfg.CONF.items()]

pprint(res)
```